# Xamarin Animation from Left to Center of the device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop an android app using Xamarin. I need the animation like images to move from left of the screen to center of the screen in home page when the app is loading for the first time.

I have tried the existing animation techniques but not satisfied it since it was always allowing to move from the current position to the next position and again back.
But I need the animation like a move from left to the current position(in the center) or right to the current position of centre.
Can someone please help to resolve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestMobileApp.MainPage">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Picker" x:Key="pickerStyle" >
            <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Frame" x:Key="frameStyle" >
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,12,50,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="OutlineColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="390">
            <!--<Image Source="Menu.PNG" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" />
            <Image HorizontalOptions="End" Source="Help.PNG" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" />-->
        </StackLayout>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="02" WidthRequest="415"></Label>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"  Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="390">
            <Label Margin="0,10,0,0"></Label>
            <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
                <Frame x:Name="processOrderFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0,0.5,0.2,0.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                    <Picker x:Name="ddlProcessOrder" Title="PROCESS ORDER" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Order1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Order2</x:String>
                            <x:String>Order3</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>
                </Frame>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
            <Frame x:Name="lookupsFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlLookups" Title="LOOKUPS" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Lookup1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Lookup2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Lookup3</x:String>
                        <x:String>Lookup4</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="qualityManagementFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlQualityManagement" Title="QUALITY STRUCTURE" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Quality1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Quality2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Quality3</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="reportsFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlReports" Title="REPORTS" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Report1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Report2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Report3</x:String>
                        <x:String>Report4</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="inventoryManagementFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlInventoryManagement" Title="INVENTORY" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Inventory1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Inventory2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Inventory3</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="documentManagementFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlDocumentManagement" Title="DOCUMENTATION" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Documentation1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Documentation2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Documentation3</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="administrationFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlAdministration" Title="ADMINISTRATION" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Administration1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Administration2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Administration4</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="siteAutomationFrame" Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
                <Picker x:Name="ddlSiteAutomation" Title="SITE AUTOMATION" Style="{StaticResource pickerStyle}" >
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Automation1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Automation2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Automation3</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

--
CS Code -

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAnimate();
        }
 private void LoadAnimate()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var xPosition = 0.5;
                var currentPosition = 0.0;
                while (currentPosition < xPosition)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    currentPosition += 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(processOrderFrame, new Rectangle(currentPosition, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2));
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: Adding a UI glimpse of what you were able to achieve will be useful. It's Xamarin.Forms right?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions which can implement it .

For example , you could use `AbsoluteLayout` and change the position of Frame

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
    <!--  -->
    <Frame x:Name="lookupsFrame" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.00,0.5,0.2,0.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

          //...

    </Frame>


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {


            var xPosition = 0.5;
            var currentPosition = 0.0;
            while (currentPosition < xPosition)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
                currentPosition += 0.04;

                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(lookupsFrame, new Rectangle(currentPosition, 0.5, 0.2,0.2));
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it is not working for me(not getting animation and control size). Im sure that i might did mistake. Could you please suggest me to resolve it.  Attached links for what i tried. In .CS file i have applied same code what you have given and changed framename , height and width . https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv2mu.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezPEm.png

Comment: Attached XAML and CS code in the above post. Actually i am trying for all the items move from left to center while opening the app.

Comment: Put all the frame in a Frame .

Comment: I tried to make it with single frame . But still not getting the animation for all items. It is mixed with all items and just moving small box. Could you please help to resolve it.

Comment: You should set the ContentView of page as AbsoluteLayout  .